# I want to add giscus comment to all jekyll posts but it doesn't work

Tags: html, github, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-extensions

Github : https://github.com/Hyun-Soon/Hyun-Soon.github.io

I'm trying to make blog with jekyll minimal mistakes theme.

I wrote _config.yml like this but I can't see giscus in my posts.

```
comments:
  provider               : giscus # false (default), "disqus", "discourse", "facebook", "staticman", "staticman_v2", "utterances", "giscus", "custom"
  disqus:
    shortname            : # https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466208-what-s-a-shortname-
  discourse:
    server               : # https://meta.discourse.org/t/embedding-discourse-comments-via-javascript/31963 , e.g.: meta.discourse.org
  facebook:
    # https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments
    appid                :
    num_posts            : # 5 (default)
    colorscheme          : # "light" (default), "dark"
  utterances:
    theme                : # "github-light" (default), "github-dark"
    issue_term           : # "pathname" (default)
  giscus:
    repo_id              : "R_kgDOKeOOEA" # Shown during giscus setup at https://giscus.app
    category_name        : "Comments" # Full text name of the category
    category_id          : "DIC_kwDOKeOOEM4CaKQd" # Shown during giscus setup at https://giscus.app
    discussion_term      : "pathname" # "pathname" (default), "url", "title", "og:title"
    reactions_enabled    : "1" # '1' for enabled (default), '0' for disabled
    theme                : "dark_dimmed" # "light" (default), "dark", "dark_dimmed", "transparent_dark", "preferred_color_sc
```

if I write this code to md files directly, I can see giscus comment box in the post

```
<script src="https://giscus.app/client.js"
        data-repo="Hyun-Soon/Hyun-Soon.github.io"
        data-repo-id="R_kgDOKeOOEA"
        data-category="Comments"
        data-category-id="DIC_kwDOKeOOEM4CaKQd"
        data-mapping="pathname"
        data-strict="0"
        data-reactions-enabled="1"
        data-emit-metadata="0"
        data-input-position="bottom"
        data-theme="dark_dimmed"
        data-lang="ko"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
        async>
</script>
```

I tried to search multiple posts about this problem, but all of them just modify _config.yml and success to make giscus comment.
Please help me

Comment: Do you have the site deployed somewhere? It would be good to see the generated HTML and any client-side errors.